# how to show tags from columns in databricks, using a sql query?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have added one specific tag to a column in one specific delta table in a data bricks catalog, but when I am using desc table , I am unable to see the tag of the columns, it just shows the column name, description and datatype

I tried desc, describe and selecting queries, I am expecting the tags to show up.

Comment: Can you explain your issue with an example or with an image of your table? Also add your code if possible for better understanding.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula , yes so suppose i have a table xyz, 
In the catalog explorer, we see few tabs like columns, sample data, details, permissions, history... 
in the 'columns' tab we see the metadata/schema of the particular table, here i can see column name, datatype, column description and tag, and i have manually added a tag to some columns,

and usually when we run a desc query for tables in db notebook, we see the contents of 'columns' tab from explorer (or the metadata), but here in this case i am unable to see 'tags' of the columns of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are a relatively new feature but to access them programmatically you can query your Databricks "System Tables"
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/information-schema/column_tags.html

```sql
SELECT 
  column_name,
  tag_name,
  tag_value
FROM system.information_schema.column_tags
WHERE
  catalog_name = 'your_catalog'
  AND schema_name = 'your_schema'
  AND table_name = 'your_table'
;
```

Tags are not included in the output of commands such as DESCRIBE at this time.